# Opencart Display Stock Quantity On Category Page

Tags: php, html, opencart, stock

We have a used furniture website running Opencart 1.5.2.1 and want to display the quantity value on the category page to allow people to know how many are in stock without clicking on the item as well as a product code/model as we have a large quantity of items on our website but some may only have a low quantity but they would have to manually check each item to find out the quantity.
I'm sure that its simple to do but my attempts have not worked. I don't need to have it so the customer can add to basket, just display the stock value. 
This is because we usually never get the same item twice so the stock value is very important.

The first answer given does not help my problem, the website is http://www.mayfairfurnitureclearance.co.uk/index.php?route=product/category&path=112_157 that link takes you straight to a category where I have been attempting this, at this minute it is displaying only a number 2 or a number 1 in some categories by using the code from the first answer and changing it to get results. Currently only displays on the "Grid" display mode as not many people use it at this time.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do bit modification in controller/catalog/category.php

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
                );
```

you need to forward Stock value to above product array and need to echo at category page e.g

```
 $this->data['products'][] = array(
                        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                        'thumb'       => $image,
                        'name'        => $result['name'],
                        'stock'       => $result['quantity']
```

in view/catalog/category.tpl

```
<div><?php echo $product['stock']; ?></div>
```

it will display like value of quantity in category page

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however it appears that it hasn't worked and I had to revert back to the old version to remove errors.

Answer (score 3):

here is another option to hide an item in category page if the stock quantity is zero.

go to controller/product/product.php

search this line:

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
```

and underneath 'name' => $result ['name'], add this code:

```
                'stock'       => $result['quantity'],
```

to become:

```
        $this->data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
            'thumb'       => $image,
            'name'        => $result['name'],
            'stock'       => $result['quantity'],
```

this will get the stock indicated in opencart.
After you add the above code, go to view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl

```
search: foreach ($products as $product) {
```

and add something like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($products as $product) { 
if($product['stock'] > 0) { ?>
```

the above code will check if the corresponding stock of each product has a quantity or not. Don't forget to close the bracket.

Happy Coding!!!